# IIS logs freeze with a lot of logs having identical timestamp at 23.59.59 UTC

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have an IIS 7.5 server, hosting a web application on .NET 4.0. I have enabled IIS logs to log requests on a daily basis. However I have observed that, after 23.59.59 the timestamp of request freezes within the log, generating a lot of logs (~1000) with that timestamp, when in reality there were hardly 5-10 requests at that point in time. Any clues?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an application issue?

Comment: I am pretty sure its not an application issue. Additionally, when I changed the setting to create new file and rollover according to local time, it is still freezing at 18.29.59 which is 5.30 hours behind my time zone.

Comment: No one seems to know anything about it. Really weird. Happens to me on IIS 8.5.